# Can't use CUDA shared memory

Tags: cudalink

CUDALink is properly installed and up to date, all built-in functions work fine, and all little functions I did worked fine... Until I tried using shared memory.
The only example I found on the help doesn't work for more than one reason. It declares the memory without a type and my compiler complains. So that's a bad start.
Anyway, I'm trying the most basic function I can, and I can't make it work.

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what's wrong, or if it works (or doesn't) for you, or give me an example that does work...
Sample code I'm trying

```
    testf = CUDAFunctionLoad["__global__ void test(int* out)
   {
    extern __shared__ int smem[];
       if(threadIdx.x==0)
    {
        smem[threadIdx.x]=7;
        out[threadIdx.x]=3;
    }else
        out[threadIdx.x]=33;
      }", "test", {{_Integer, "Output"}}, 16];
```

When I run it I get a *CUDAFunction::internal: `CUDALink` experienced an internal error. >>* and then I need to restart the kernel to make `CUDALink` work again

```
testf[Range[16], 16]
```

Just commenting out the line with the `smem[threadIdx.x]=7` assignment makes it work. The compiler issues no warnings

Answer (score 6):

This [*Mathematica* 8 documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0d195cdqgdtuw44ioyvm6og9pu-bjuef1) should answer your question.

Comment: +1 I can't believe I didn't see that section of "Scope" that looks helpful... Thanks... Edit your answer that I had to add "Shared" at the end of the list of arguments in CUDAFunctionLoad and you get an accept

Comment: Can you please summarize the answer or at least, address the _"I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what's wrong..."_ part of the question? Mere link only answers are not encouraged here :)